# Is there an alternative to Microsoft Scripting Runtime library in Excel VVA for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, vba, dictionary, excel

I have a workbook with plenty of VBA on it, many using the `Dictionary` object. The problem is that Excel for Mac OS X doesn't seem to have the "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library, thus, no `Dictionary` object.

How could I solve this issue? Is there any alternative library? Any alternative Dictionary class?

Comment: Check the answers at [VBA (Excel) Dictionary on Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869266/vba-excel-dictionary-on-mac) for a dictionary replacement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Collection instead of Dictionary, and my problem <strike>is now solved now</strike> is now partially solved, as Collection seems to be native.

UPDATE: The problem is that Dictionary has some more features, like iterating through the keys. But I could work around this in my specific case.

Comment: I am trying to make a workbook that will work on Mac and PC the same, on OS X what did you select to replace Microsoft Scripting RunTime? I only ask because I need it on the PC and as you say it doesn't exist on the Mac... I have Office 2011, I was hoping it would by now.

Comment: Hi, Matt. As I said, I ended up using Collection that is native on Mac OS X, but I don't believe it is on Excel. At the end, I had to rewrite the code for there was another issues. Maybe the better you do is to abstract most of the logic to separate modules and replace then on each OS.