# Missing Tool References

Tags: excel, vba, macos

My version of VBA seems to be missing quite a few Tool References. Therefore I tried adding a library I know exists (scrrun.dll) through the "Browse" tab although it only results in the following error:

[image: Error]

I would appreciate any kind of help regarding how to get access to more tool references.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Office?

Comment: @TinMan : Why should he reinstall Office ??

Comment: @Johan: Why do you think you are missing a few Tool References? ( Especially why scrrun.dll ?)

Comment: https://newretas.netlify.app/enable-microsoft-scripting-runtime-excel-for-mac.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19869266/vba-excel-dictionary-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

A reinstall may help, but these references may be pointing to a folder from a different version of windows (*\System32 vs *\SysWow64 may be the issue)

What changed from the system it originally ran on?  Search the C: drive for `SCRRUN.DLL` and if the path has changed, switch that via browsing for the real path.  I've never seen that file missing before, but I think it's part of Windows.

On a rare occasion, you may have to re-register the components (again some of these are included Windows components). [Check out this reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/949140/when-i-run-a-script-in-windows-script-i-receive-an-error-message-libra)

Comment: It's clear from the screenshot it's Office for Mac.

Comment: ahhh... well it can happen with varying versions, locations, of that?  Do you have those paths?

Comment: Appears the issue is porting from Windows, to the Mac, if these references don't exist :(

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I run excel on a Mac. I've tried reinstalling excel multiple times but the missing references doesn't seem to be added to the correct path. At first it seemed that another program on my computer had hijacked the path folder containing all references for VBA as `scrrun.dll` and other references could be found within the folder of this program. So I tried deleting this program and its files before reinstalling Excell but now I can't find the missing reference files at all. VBA only grants access to 14 references which seems quite weird.